# Error ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle

In Eclipse i'm getting this error: **Error ORA-01000: maximum open cursors exceeded
I have already close connexion in the block finally, but  i don't know why i'm getting this error, here is my code JAVA.
Please help me!

```
 for (DossierAMO dos = null; it.hasNext();) {
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            PreparedStatement ps2 = null;
            ResultSet rs2 = null;
            try {
                dos = (DossierAMO) it.next();   
                //PreparedStatement ps = null;
                //ResultSet rs = null;
                /*try
                 * 
                {*/
                System.out.println("Imma"+dos.getImma());
                    ps = cnnOracle.getConnexion().prepareStatement(
                            "select count(IMM_IMM_V_NUM_IMM) from d_salaire@prod_dist where SAL_C_DS =21 and IMM_IMM_V_NUM_IMM =?",
                            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
                            );
                    ps.setString(1,dos.getImma());
                    rs = ps.executeQuery();
                    if (rs.next()){

                        if (rs.getInt(1) != 0)
                            //System.out.println("> Ecriture des dossiers d'indus dans le fichier d'indus2");
                            fichierIndius2.ecrireDossier(dos);
                        else
                        {


                            ps2 = cnnOracle.getConnexion().prepareStatement(
                            "select count(DOS_N_NUM_DOS) from d_dossier@prod_dist where IMM_IMM_V_NUM_IMM =?",
                            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY,
                            ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
                            );
                            ps2.setString(1,dos.getImma()); 
                            rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                            if (rs2.next()){

                            if (rs2.getInt(1) != 0)

                            fichierIndius2.ecrireDossier(dos);

                            else{
                fichierIndius.ecrireDossier(dos);
        }}}}
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                requete.fermer();

                fichierIndius.fermerSansException();
                fichierIndius2.fermerSansException();
                cnnAS400.fermerConnexion();
                cnnAS400FO.fermerConnexion();
                cnnOracle.fermerConnexion();
                System.err
                        .println("Erreur d'écriture dans le fichier d'indus! /        EXC : "
                                + ex);
                return;
            }
            finally{

                if (rs != null)
                    try {
                        rs.close();
                    } catch (Exception exx) {
                    }
                if (rs2 != null)
                    try {
                        rs2.close();
                    } catch (Exception exx) {
                    }
                if (ps != null)
                    try {
                        ps.close();
                    } catch (Exception exx) {
                    }
                if (ps2 != null)
                    try {
                        ps2.close();
                    } catch (Exception exx) {
                    }
            }






        }
```

Comment: Why are you setting `rs` and `ps` to null? That will stop those being closed in the finally block. And you're *trying* to close `ps` instead of `ps2` as well. When do you think you are closing the connections - since you don't have variables pointing to the two you open? (Except maybe in the exception handler, depending what those calls do.)

Comment: Alex i have modified these lines but i'm still getting the same error!

Comment: Modifying the question after it's been answered isn't very helpful. You still aren't closing the connections though.

Comment: Should i close connections in the block finally?

Comment: @salma. I have to commend you for trying to solve this problem. All too often, customers simply bump up the open_cursors parameter as a "fix". I'm sure the smart folks in this group will get to the root of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are (or were) setting `rs` and `ps` to null in the `else`, i.e. when `rc.getInt(1) == 0`. That meens that when you get to the finally block, these tests would fail, and `ps` and `rs` could not be closed:

```
            if (rs != null)
                try {
                    rs.close();
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                }
            ....
            if (ps != null)
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                }
```

As @APC already pointed out, you are also (or were) closing the wrong statement here:

```
            if (ps2 != null)
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                }
```

The bigger problem is that you don't free your connection(s) as you claimed. There is a call to `cnnOracle.fermerConnexion()`, but *only* in an exception handler:

```
...
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            requete.fermer();

            fichierIndius.fermerSansException();
            fichierIndius2.fermerSansException();
            cnnAS400.fermerConnexion();
            cnnAS400FO.fermerConnexion();
            cnnOracle.fermerConnexion();
            System.err
                    .println("Erreur d'écriture dans le fichier d'indus! /        EXC : "
                            + ex);
            return;
        }
        finally{
...
```

You need to close the connection in the finally block as well, after you (correctly) close the statements and result sets.

You also need to look at what `cnnOracle.fermerConnexion()` is doing. You call `cnnOracle.getConnexion()` twice, once for each of your prepared statements. If those return *different* connections, and `fermerConnexion()` only closes one, you're leaking there too. You'll need to investigate what happen inside each of them.

It would be more normal to use one connection, so you have a variable called say `conn` that you set with `cnnOracle.getConnexion()`, and then create your prepared statments as `ps = conn.prepareStatement(...)`.

You currently seem to be getting connections and recreating and destroying the prepared statements inside a loop. It would be much more efficient to get the connection and prepare the statements once before the loop, and just execute them inside the loop. And then close the prepared statements and connection after the loop completes (and still in the exception handler, since that returns to the caller, and the finally block for the try block will no longer close them).

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your response, i try to follow what you mention in my code, but now i'm getting the error message:  java.lang.NullPointerException.

Comment: I simply forget to instantiate the prepared statement with null. Now it works. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

> " i don't know why i'm getting this error"

Could it be this typo?

```
            if (ps2 != null)
                try {
                    ps.close();
                } catch (Exception exx) {
                }
```

You're closing `ps` not `ps2`

Comment: APC, i modified that but i'm still getting the same error!

Comment: what do the functions fichierIndius2.ecrireDossier(dos); and fichierIndius.ecrireDossier(dos); ? Do they have something to do with db ? If yes can you post the code ?

Comment: also the cnnOracle.getConnexion()., what does it do ?

Comment: Its gets a connexion, it's a class defined in an another project.